Do amenable groups have invariant monotiles?
Let $G$ be a countable, discrete, amenable group, and let $B$ a finite subset. We say that $B$ is a monotile if $G$ is a disjoint union of translated copies of $B$. In "Monotilable Amenable Groups", by Benjamin Weiss, he proved that if $G$ is residually finite, then there is a Følner sequence of monotiles.Is it known wether this holds for all amenable groups? If it is known, is there a reference I could read? If not, is there another condition (aside from residually finite) that can ensure this property?
Thanks in advance for any answer!
